# Does find_in_batches uses different DB connection for each batch?

Tags: activerecord

I'm thinking of using *sleep* within *find_in_batches* to wait before processing the batch. Is it a right way to do? I'm wondering, does this block the DB connection? Or it just uses different DB connections for each batch in which case I can use the *sleep* without worrying too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_in_batches` does not reserve a connection, it simply picks a connection from ActiveRecord's connection pool each time a new batch is yielded. You can use sleep safely. As to it being a right thing to do, you'd have to specify why you want to use the sleep in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I'm creating a new job for each record and I don't want to create 1000s of jobs at the same time.

Comment: You should probably start by checking if it really is a problem, then throttling if needed. I'd say it depends on how your jobs work, if it's a Sidekiq, then pushing values to Redis should need no sleeps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still exploring that option (I'm not ready yet for Sidekiq Enterprise). But before that, I wanted to clarify my above doubt.